# How to add conditional parameter to jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

I want to add a conditional parameter to jenkins job. In other words, I want to add a boolean parameter when checked, another string parameter appears to the user when they build the job. If not checked the string parameter should not appear as a parameter when the user builds the job (Kind of a similar behaviour to the conditional steps of jenkins but on parameters.). Is their a plugin for that?

In the image below, if repo_update is not checked: Clean and Changesets should not be present to the user if they are building the job. 
[image]

Comment: I suggest to simply use a string parameter where it defaults to an empty string which triggers the default build and only triggers the different build chain when non-empty

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the [Multi job plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin)

Make the parent and child two separate jobs. This to me makes more sense logically.

In the build part, run the parent job first.

Based on a condition, the child job can run.

You can add the child params in the child job only, so people who configure the parent job will never see the child params

This to me feels like a cleaner implementation.

Comment: Problem is, It's not just a string parameter. They are multiple parameters. A string and two boolean variables. Can I construct a boolean condition from these?

Comment: Sure thats just a shell issue. I edited my answer to show how you can do it. 

But really if the child job is not triggered, why are you worried about the parent job's params?

Comment: could you take a look at the update that I posted?....I elaborated what I want to do... Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, but what I'm saying is if the conditional is false, then the params have no meaning, since they are never used. I think you are overthinking this. 

If the parent job does not run the child job because of the boolean parameter (here called TRIGGER_CHILD_JOB), then the values of the child param will never be used anyway. If I am not understanding this problem, post a more detailed question, with the params from the parent job, what will be specified to the child and so on.

Comment: yup you are correct, I understand that it won't make a difference from the logical perspective. It's just from the UX perspective, It doesn't make sense for the parameters of the child job to be present to the user if they didn't check to run it from the parent job.

Comment: IN that case the simple "if" statement I presented removed the param values, so the user wont see anything.

Comment: check the image added, I guess it will help you visualize what I have in mind

Comment: Edited my answer after seeing your image.

Comment: I don't understand. The parent and the child are already two separate jobs. I want the parent job to trigger the child job conditionally and I already did that. What I wanted is for the child's parameters' that are passed from the parent to not appear in the parent if the child job will not be triggered.